# format the Database Query string in Katalon

Tags: sql, katalon-studio

how to format the Query string in Katalon.

Katalon shows warning for the statement inside the quote ""

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM dis.disA where lower(data) LIKE '%state":"new%'"
```

the original data in database column is in json format like this

```
{"Id":"4518112019012505","LocationId":"locationid","State":"NEW","Items":[{"ItemReports":[],"Id":"a1d5c0de-4592-4b2d-833f-993fd2173e13","Quantity":20}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it by myself

use the / instead ""

```
String dbQuery = /SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM dis.disA where lower(data) LIKE '%"state":"new"%'/
```